# VSCode C++ IntelliSense doesn't see files in project directories

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I am developing in Visual Studio Code a C++ application, for which a linter is fundamental.

**Compiler **(Makefile) OK ✔ **Intellisense **ERROR **X**.

My PC is Windows, but I use the Remote Explorer with SSH on a Linux server/machine**. Target platform(OS) for the application is Linux.

I installed the C/C++ package with IntelliSense, followed setup guides and troubleshooting, but for some reasons I still get a:

`cannot open source file "header.h"`

Where `header.h` is a file from another directory in my project.
when importing header files from my own project.
My project directory tree looks like this:

```
home/project/    //--> this is my ${workspaceFolder}
----include/
--------header1.h
--------header2.h
----src/specific_implement/
--------implementation.cpp
```

Reasuming:

- `#include "header1.h" // in header2.h file OK`
- `#include <stdio.h>  // any file           OK`
- `#include "header1.h" // in implementation.cpp file ERROR`

I tried installing an older version of the C/C++ package and it worked for 1 day, then reopening the project broke everything again.

I edited the `c_cpp_properties.json` file adding the specific path that contains my include, but I still get the error.

My json file looks like this:

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/home/project/include/"
            ],
     "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                    "/home/project/include/"
                ],
```

Browse path recognised the file the day IntelliSense worked...

Comment: See [C/C++ extension FAQ](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/faq-cpp#_how-do-i-get-intellisense-to-work-correctly) on the documentation of Visual Studio Code. Make sure that the editor is configured to use information from your build system such as CMake.

Comment: I am not using CMake but a custom made Makefile. But I will try to look into what you said

Comment: To generate `compile_commands.json` from `Makefile`s, you may use [bear](https://github.com/rizsotto/Bear).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your C_Cpp: Intelli Sense Engine is disabled

Go to File -> Preferences -> Settings or Ctrl+,

Search Intelli Sense Engine and set to Default.